# one particular laptop does not receive UDP broadcast messages

Tags: wifi, udp

I am trying to debug a problem with a particular laptop which is running Ubuntu.  We have a service which uses broadcast UDP messages, and this laptop is not receiving them on its wireless interface, except occasionally.

I have boiled the problem down to an example using `netcat` and `socat` to demonstrate.  I am temporarily using a wireless router with 192.168.0.X address range.

On one computer I run

```
$ nc -lu 7570
```

And on the other computer I run

```
$ echo "hello" | socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.0.255:7570,broadcast
```

This shows up on all computers connected via wireless except the one in question.  If I run `socat` on the "bad" computer all computers see the message including itself.

Oddly, everything else about this computer seems fine.  It is able to use wireless to browse the net and transfer files with no problems.  It only won't receive UDP broadcast messages.  If I put the "socat" in a loop, it will receive the message once every 100 times or so.  Also, it seems to work fine on the wired connection.  So it must be a problem with the `r8192se_pci` driver which it uses for its wireless chipset.  However, I've never heard of such a problem where all traffic works fine *except* for broadcast messages.  Can anyone think of how I might fix or better-diagnose the problem?

Comment: Can you set the interface to promiscuous mode? If so, does that change it's behavior?

Comment: Have you tried sending it unicast UDP messages at the same time as you're sending the broadcast messages and seeing if they go through? UDP isn't reliable and neither is wireless.

Answer (score 1):

Steve, this sounds very suspiciously like mismatched netmasks between the devices on the subnet... I would check that Ubuntu's netmask with `ip addr show`.